# Execute Shell Scrip individually for each selected file in Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder, automator, script

I am trying to create an automator workflow that will do a google search for the filename of each selected file in finder.

Unfortunately  the workflow I have created works just with one selected file.  If I select multiple files it doesn't work.

How can I set the Shell Scrip to be executed individually for each selected file in Finder?

[image: Screenshot of Automator Workflow]

I have used a custom 'Get Names of Finder Items' Automator Action  downloaded from [here](http://www.menace-enterprises.com/Files/Automator/Actions/Get%20Names%20of%20Finder%20Items.dmg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a shell script such as the following that will run the command each time for each of the arguments:

```
for f in "$@"
do
  open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$f"
done
```